# VBA Projects deleting rows

Tags: excel, vba

I receive a daily email with an excel spreadsheet.  The number of rows can Varey I'm trying to write an excel macro that formats the data.

I need the VBA code to delete the first two rows of an excel spreadsheet.  Also, the last two rows after the last row of data needs to be deleted.  These rows are merged and I need to be removed.

My current formula deletes the last two rows of data that still contains information.
The first two rows delete fine.

```
Sub NTWpenPOReport()

'It's my understand the below line will help the the macro run faster.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Rows("1:2").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Selection.End(xlDown).Delete

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

image of code in BVA.

Comment: Also, avoid using `Select` and `Selection`, instead use fully qualified objects. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: `to delete the first two columns` `the last two columns after` Do you want to delete `columns` or `rows`?  `These columns are merged` please edit your post to show merged rows.

Answer (score 0):

- Assumes OP is looking for the code to remove rows.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DelRows()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Rows(LastRow - 1 & ":" & LastRow).Delete
    Rows("1:2").Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: I get a Run-time error '1004':  Application-defined or object-defined error on                           ** Row (LastRow - 1 & ":" & LastRow).Delete**

Comment: Is there merged cell?

Comment: yes - the 2 columns after the last row of date is merged.

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of `2 columns after the last row`. A screenshot is helpful.